# Summing up lines with a common field

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file like this:

```
paper 3
paper 6
eraser 2
pencil 9
pencil 44
pencil 1
```

I would like to sum up the lines with a common first field, like this:

```
paper 9
eraser 2
pencil 54
```

Is there a cute one liner to do this using standard Unix utilities? Or even not-so-standard Unix utilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to this:

```
$ echo "$a"
paper 3
paper 6
eraser 2
pencil 9
pencil 44
pencil 1

$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]+$2}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' <(echo "$a")
pencil 54
eraser 2
paper 9
```

Replace `<(echo "$a)` with your `file` :

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]+$2}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

Comment: Very nice! I chose this one because it's simple and awk is available pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

With the not-so-standard utility [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
$ datamash --whitespace groupby 1 sum 2 < file
paper   9
eraser  2
pencil  54
```

or more succinctly

```
$ datamash -Wg 1 sum 2 < file
paper   9
eraser  2
pencil  54
```

Answer (score 2):

If we care about the order of printing then we can do this:

```
perl -lane '$h{$F[0]}+=$F[1]; $h[-1+keys%h]=$F[0]; END{print "$_ $h{$_}" for @h}'
```

The idea being to maintain the running sums of a particular item in the hash `%h` and the order in which the particular item was seen in the `@h` array. At the end of file, we just print the hash(key+value) but taking the order from `@h` array.

## Result

```
paper 9
eraser 2
pencil 54
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a not-so-cute one liner in awk:

```
awk '{ if (prev && prev != $1) { print prev, sum; sum = 0 }; sum += $2; prev = $1 } END { print prev, sum }' < file.txt
```

It requires that lines with the same value in the first field be grouped together. If this is not the case, you can `sort file.txt | awk ...`.